# Destructurization of all object properties

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Is there a possibility of destructurization assignment of an object without specifying all properties so that all properties become available without accessing the object.
`let props = {one: "property1", two: "property2"};`

so that you can take the property to the console
`console.log(one);`

Something like
`let {...} = props;`

Comment: I take it this is about JS?  It needs the tag if so.

Comment: To what end? In other words: why do you want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically naming variables is inherently risky and not recommended. The problem is you're taking some object and trusting it to overwrite any existing variable (including things like `console.log`). If you're confident of your own code and you're just being lazy, I'd still recommend being verbose and [enumerating all properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), or maybe assigning it to a variable with a shorter name.

That said, here are the methods I know of to do this...

### Assigning to the global `window` scope

This works specifically in a web browser and is the only safe way. You should always check if a property exists first before writing to it for some protection. It is still error-prone because it can still affect other code, and it'll be hard to code using variable names only known at runtime. However it effectively lets you do what you're asking for, with some extra code:

```
let props = {one: "property1", two: "property2"};
for (p in props) {
    if (!(p in window)) {
        window[p] = props[p];
    }
}
console.log(one); // property1
console.log(two); // property2
```

### [`with(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/with) statement

This is an old way, and simple to use. It adds onto the scope within a block to include all of an object's properties. This includes prototype functions and everything. The code ends up looking like this:

```
let props = {one: "property1", two: "property2"};
with (props) {
    console.log(one); // property1
    console.log(two); // property2
}
```

A big problem with this is if the object is coming from somewhere else, like a function parameter, then it could override the scope of local variables you hard coded. The linked documentation lists lots of problems using this feature.

### [`eval(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) destructuring

This is probably more of what you were thinking of. You can manually create a list of properties to assign as variables, and then put it in a destructoring assignment within `eval(...)`. This ends up looking like this:

```
let props = {one: "property1", two: "property2"};
eval(`var {${Object.keys(props).join()}}=props`)
console.log(one); // property1
console.log(two); // property2
```

This is different in two ways. The only way to create new variables inside `eval(...)` is in the global scope, so it's not self-contained. However it does only include the object's [own properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn), meaning nothing will be copied from the prototype. MDN also details problems with using this.